# How to get list of all registred routes

Tags: model-view-controller, routes

I am creating RouteLink extension method, and for that I need to know all registred routes in application where I will pick a right route name. How can I access rotetable from HtmlHelper extension method ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a static RouteCollection where are all registred routes stored.

```
System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes
```